# Convert Array of object to new Object for Fingerprinting app

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

I am working on BLE Fingerprinting app.
I have save data received to database and then converting it to csv file .

---

**Data received**

```
[
  { id: '45:32:BC:3E:67:CD', name: 'beacon1', rssi: -78, region: 1 },
  { id: '71:B2:51:E7:91:C0', name: 'beacon2', rssi: -52, region: 1 },
  { id: '73:CD:84:44:DA:BE', name: 'beacon3', rssi: -53, region: 1 },
  { id: '4F:6E:FA:E7:E1:5B', name: 'beacon4', rssi: -53, region: 1 }
]
```

**To**

```
{region:1, beacon1: -78, beacon2: -52, beacon3: -53, beacon4: -53}
```

**In Javascript**

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yeah I tried many approach with map and reduce but was not able make sense

Comment: try `const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => { acc['regiion'] = item.region; acc[ item.name ] = item.rssi; return acc;  }, {})`

Comment: Saurabh, remember to always share your effort, be it a search history or partial code. That tells us what you are missing and we can help you learn instead of just solving your 1 problem

Comment: const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => { acc['region'] = item.region; acc[ item.name ] = item.rssi; return acc; }, {})
This Worked  Thank you!! Actually I am new to Stackoverflow

Comment: @SaurabhPatel I have posted answer just for your question, you can optimize it more if you want OR  Rajesh sir can edit code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using simple loop is the optimized way but you can use the following code to get the specific result.

```js
let response = [
     { id: '45:32:BC:3E:67:CD', name: 'beacon1', rssi: -78, region: 1 },
     { id: '71:B2:51:E7:91:C0', name: 'beacon2', rssi: -52, region: 1 },
     { id: '73:CD:84:44:DA:BE', name: 'beacon3', rssi: -53, region: 1 },
     { id: '4F:6E:FA:E7:E1:5B', name: 'beacon4', rssi: -53, region: 1 }
    ]
    let obj = {};
    for (i in response) {
     obj.region = response[i].region;
     obj[response[i].name] = response[i].rssi;
    }
    
    console.log(obj);
```

OR you can use more functional approach:

```js
let response = [
  { id: '45:32:BC:3E:67:CD', name: 'beacon1', rssi: -78, region: 1 },
  { id: '71:B2:51:E7:91:C0', name: 'beacon2', rssi: -52, region: 1 },
  { id: '73:CD:84:44:DA:BE', name: 'beacon3', rssi: -53, region: 1 },
  { id: '4F:6E:FA:E7:E1:5B', name: 'beacon4', rssi: -53, region: 1 }
]
const result = response.reduce((acc, { name, region, rssi }) => ( { ...acc, region, [name]: rssi } ), {} );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: careful, this works only as long as there is just a single `region` and/or you don't want to differentiate by `region`